# HSQLDB optional IN parameter or default parameter value of stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, hsqldb, default-value, optional-values

how can I set **default value** for an **IN parameter** of a **stored procedure** or
how can I set an IN **parameter to optional** in a stored procedure
in **HSQLDB**?

I have already tried all of the solution what I learned in SQL generally
and I have already red through the HSQLDB reference
and unfortunately I didn't find the answer yet.

Do you have any experience with this?

Thank you for your answer in advance!

K.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set default values for an IN parameter. This is a non-standard feature of some products.

There are ways to add some flexibility:

1. Inside the procedure check if the parameter is NULL and if so, use a default value
2. Define two or three versions of the procedure. The versions with fewer parameters call the one with the largest number of parameters. The full version checks for NULL and used the default.

Comment: Hi fredt
thank you for your quick answer!
1., with this solution you can't call the stored procedure with different number of parameter - cause SQL failure if you call a stored procedure with less/more number of parameter than you defined it
2., you can't create more than one SQL object with the same name
K.

Comment: You can define multiple stored procedure with the same name so long as they have different number of parameters.

Comment: Non of the SQLs support this on the planet Earth.

"SQL-invoked routines are schema objects. Naming and referencing follows conventions common to all schema objects." 
http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html

There can't exist two SQL object with the same name in the same schema in SQL.

Comment: HSQLDB supports polymorphic routines. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_polymorphis.

Comment: Also see this section: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_routine_polymorphism

Comment: @Kata: PostgreSQL supports overloading, and so does Oracle (inside of packages)